# set variable in windows form powershell textinput VB

Tags: forms, powershell, variables

I took me hours to get this working, does anyone know how to set a variable hostname, workgroup when I hit install? I tried several options but couldn't make it work. After the variable has been insert i can add a command to the handler_button1_click just before the form.closed.

It would be even more perfect that if the hostname gives a error it would go back to form1 to re-enter that hostname.

```
function GenerateForm {

[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null

$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$listBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$checkBox3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$checkBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$checkBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState

$b1= $false
$b2= $false
$b3= $false

#----------------------------------------------
#Generated Event Script Blocks
#----------------------------------------------

$handler_button1_Click= 
{
    if ($checkBox1.Checked)     
    {
    Write-Host "Install SysTrax OnTrax " -NoNewLine
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path c:\sysadmin\baseinstall\apps -Force  | Out-Null
    $URL = "https://www.systrax.nl/download/ONTRAX_AGENT.EXE"
    $Output = "c:\sysadmin\baseinstall\apps\ONTRAX_AGENT.EXE"
    $Silent = "/silent"
    Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $output -Priority Foreground
    & $Output $Silent
    while (!(Test-Path "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Advanced Monitoring Agent.lnk")) { Start-Sleep 5 }
    }

    if ($checkBox2.Checked)    
    {  
    Write-Host "Install HP Support Assistant " -NoNewLine
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path c:\sysadmin\baseinstall\apps -Force  | Out-Null
    $URL = "https://www.systrax.nl/download/HPSupportAssistant.exe"
    $Output = "c:\sysadmin\baseinstall\apps\HPSupportAssistant.exe"
    $Silent = "/S"
    Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $output -Priority Foreground
    & $Output $Silent
    Write-Host "- DONE" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen -BackgroundColor green
    while (!(Test-Path "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\HP Support Assistant.lnk")) { Start-Sleep 5 }
    }

    if ($checkBox3.Checked)    
    {
    Invoke-Item C:\Windows
    }
    $form1.Close()
}

$OnLoadForm_StateCorrection=
{#Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
    $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
}

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Code
$form1.Text = "Systrax External Apps"
$form1.Name = "form1"
$form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 300
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 160
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
$form1.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$form1.Topmost = $True

$mhostname = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$mhostname.Text="hostname" 
$mhostname.Top="25" 
$mhostname.Left="10" 
$mhostname.Anchor="Left,Top" 
$mhostname.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,23) 
$form1.Controls.Add($mhostname) 

$mworkgroup = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$mworkgroup.Text="workgroup" 
$mworkgroup.Top="50" 
$mworkgroup.Left="10" 
$mworkgroup.Anchor="Left,Top" 
$mworkgroup.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,23) 
$form1.Controls.Add($mworkgroup) 

$button1.TabIndex = 4
$button1.Name = "button1"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 75
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
$button1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$button1.Text = "Install"
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 10
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 130
$button1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$button1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$button1.add_Click($handler_button1_Click)
$form1.Controls.Add($button1)

$checkBox3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 140
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 24
$checkBox3.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$checkBox3.TabIndex = 2
$checkBox3.Text = "Spare"
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 150
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 75
$checkBox3.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$checkBox3.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$checkBox3.Name = "checkBox3"
$form1.Controls.Add($checkBox3)

$checkBox2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 140
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 24
$checkBox2.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$checkBox2.TabIndex = 1
$checkBox2.Text = "HP Support Assistant"
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 150
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 50
$checkBox2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$checkBox2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$checkBox2.Name = "checkBox2"
$form1.Controls.Add($checkBox2)

$checkBox1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 140
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 24
$checkBox1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$checkBox1.TabIndex = 0
$checkBox1.Text = "SysTrax OnTrax"
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 150
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 25
$checkBox1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$checkBox1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$checkBox1.Name = "checkBox1"
$form1.Controls.Add($checkBox1)

#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$form1.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
#Show the Form
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null

} #End Function

#Call the Function
GenerateForm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works :) finally

```
function GenerateForm {

[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null

$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$listBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$checkBox3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$checkBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$checkBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState

$b1= $false
$b2= $false
$b3= $false

#----------------------------------------------
#Generated Event Script Blocks
#----------------------------------------------

$handler_button1_Click= 
{
    if ($checkBox1.Checked)     
    {
    Write-Host "Install SysTrax OnTrax " -NoNewLine
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path c:\sysadmin\baseinstall\apps -Force  | Out-Null
    $URL = "https://www.systrax.nl/download/ONTRAX_AGENT.EXE"
    $Output = "c:\sysadmin\baseinstall\apps\ONTRAX_AGENT.EXE"
    $Silent = "/silent"
    Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $output -Priority Foreground
    & $Output $Silent
    while (!(Test-Path "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Advanced Monitoring Agent.lnk")) { Start-Sleep 5 }
    }

    if ($checkBox2.Checked)    
    {  
    Write-Host "Install HP Support Assistant " -NoNewLine
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path c:\sysadmin\baseinstall\apps -Force  | Out-Null
    $URL = "https://www.systrax.nl/download/HPSupportAssistant.exe"
    $Output = "c:\sysadmin\baseinstall\apps\HPSupportAssistant.exe"
    $Silent = "/S"
    Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $output -Priority Foreground
    & $Output $Silent
    Write-Host "- DONE" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen -BackgroundColor green
    while (!(Test-Path "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\HP Support Assistant.lnk")) { Start-Sleep 5 }
    }

    if ($checkBox3.Checked)    
    {
    Invoke-Item C:\Windows
    }
    #Change hostname
    Rename-Computer -NewName $mhostname.Text
    #Change workgroupname
    Add-Computer -WorkGroupName $mworkgroup.Text
    $form1.Close()
}

$OnLoadForm_StateCorrection=
{#Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
    $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
}

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Code
$form1.Text = "Systrax External Apps"
$form1.Name = "form1"
$form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 300
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 160
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
$form1.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$form1.Topmost = $True

$mhostname = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$mhostname.Text="hostname" 
$mhostname.Top="25" 
$mhostname.Left="10" 
$mhostname.Anchor="Left,Top" 
$mhostname.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,23) 
$form1.Controls.Add($mhostname) 

$mworkgroup = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$mworkgroup.Text="workgroup" 
$mworkgroup.Top="50" 
$mworkgroup.Left="10" 
$mworkgroup.Anchor="Left,Top" 
$mworkgroup.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,23) 
$form1.Controls.Add($mworkgroup) 

$button1.TabIndex = 4
$button1.Name = "button1"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 75
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
$button1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$button1.Text = "Install"
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 10
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 130
$button1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$button1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$button1.add_Click($handler_button1_Click)
$form1.Controls.Add($button1)

$checkBox3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 140
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 24
$checkBox3.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$checkBox3.TabIndex = 2
$checkBox3.Text = "Spare"
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 150
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 75
$checkBox3.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$checkBox3.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$checkBox3.Name = "checkBox3"
$form1.Controls.Add($checkBox3)

$checkBox2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 140
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 24
$checkBox2.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$checkBox2.TabIndex = 1
$checkBox2.Text = "HP Support Assistant"
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 150
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 50
$checkBox2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$checkBox2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$checkBox2.Name = "checkBox2"
$form1.Controls.Add($checkBox2)

$checkBox1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 140
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 24
$checkBox1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$checkBox1.TabIndex = 0
$checkBox1.Text = "SysTrax OnTrax"
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 150
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 25
$checkBox1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$checkBox1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$checkBox1.Name = "checkBox1"
$form1.Controls.Add($checkBox1)

#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$form1.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
#Show the Form
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null

} #End Function

#Call the Function
GenerateForm
```